# Firebase authentication error with react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RNFirebase from 'react-native-firebase';


const firebase = RNFirebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'KEY',
    authDomain: 'APPNAME.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://APPNAME-#####.firebaseio.com/',
    projectId: 'APPNAME-#####'});

export default firebase;
```

This is my code (with replacements obviously) I've added the required pods and the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file also.

I'm getting the error

> "Failed to initialize app. FirebaseOptions missing or invalid "appID"
>   property"

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 3):

If you have set up your application properly, you do not need to do a second initializeApp as that is done for you automatically. You should just import firebase and be on your merry way per the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/installation/javascript).

If what you are trying to do is to do multiple initializations, or manual ones for that matter, you need to check the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/core/initialize-apps) for that. Basically your configuration is not complete, as full configuration is;

```
// pluck values from your `GoogleService-Info.plist` you created on the firebase console
const iosConfig = {
  clientId: 'x',
  appId: 'x',
  apiKey: 'x',
  databaseURL: 'x',
  storageBucket: 'x',
  messagingSenderId: 'x',
  projectId: 'x',

  // enable persistence by adding the below flag
  persistence: true,
};

// pluck values from your `google-services.json` file you created on the firebase console
const androidConfig = {
  clientId: 'x',
  appId: 'x',
  apiKey: 'x',
  databaseURL: 'x',
  storageBucket: 'x',
  messagingSenderId: 'x',
  projectId: 'x',

  // enable persistence by adding the below flag
  persistence: true,
};
```